# Strongly Typed DataSets and System.Data.DataRowBuilder?

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

I am converting some old V1.1 VB code. It uses a Strongly typed dataset. Then the person was able to do things like:

```
Dim myDs As NewDataSet = New NewDataSet
Dim myMbrIfcReqRow As NewDataSet.MbrIfcReqRow
```

I generated the same Strongly Typed DataSet in C# with xsd.exe. But when I try these same statements:

NewDataSet myDs = new NewDataSet();
    NewDataSet.MbrIfcReqRow myMbrIfcReqRow = new NewDataSet.MbrIfcReqRow();

It says that "MbrIfcReqRow has 1 parameter but is invoked with 0 aruements." It is indeed.  It has a parameter System.DataRowBilder. What do I do with that. it is in the generated code:

```
internal MbrIfcReqRow(global::System.Data.DataRowBuilder rb) : 
                base(rb) {
            this.tableMbrIfcReq = ((MbrIfcReqDataTable)(this.Table));
```

If I have to override the constructor how and where do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataRow` objects must always be associated with a `DataTable`; you cannot use that constructor directly.

Instead, call the generated `yourTable.NewMbrIfcReqRow()` method.

Comment: I'm using a DataSet not a DataTable. There is no myDs.NewMbrIfcReqRow() method.

Comment: NewDataSet.MbrIfcReqRow myMbrIfcReqRow = new NewDataSet.MbrIfcReqRow();

Comment: I found NewMbrIfcReqRow in the generated code but how do I reference it? I can't reference it through myDs.

Comment: NewMbrIfcReqRow is in the NewDataSet.MbrIfcReqDataTable class but I don't have that, I have a data set only. How do I get the typed data table?

Comment: @SamGentile: Your typed dataset class will have a property for each table.  Or just create the table instead of the dataset.